# Is there any way to delay the launch of a third party app?

Tags: java, android

Say I have an accessibility service and I'm using it to detect when certain apps are launched. What I need is to run a few lines of code **before** these apps are launched. It's important that this code is executed before an app is launched not after, otherwise the code would have no effect.

What I'm currently capable of is:

*App gets launched --> Accessibility service detects launch --> Accessibility service runs some code*

What I need is:

*App gets launched --> Accessibility service detects this launch and stops it somehow --> Accessibility service runs some code --> App now gets to launch*

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Read about how anti virus software works.

Comment: dude that's not answer. Even if I do read up on them it's probably going to be something abstract. I'm asking about a specific method in Android to delay or stop the launch of an app, either that or a way for accessibility services to run code before an app gets to launch.

Comment: "Say I have an accessibility service and I'm using it to detect when certain apps are launched" -- that is not the role of an accessibility service. "How do I go about doing this?" -- there is nothing in the Android SDK for this, for obvious security reasons.

Comment: @CommonsWare as you might know I'm already doing it :)

Comment: @CommonsWare https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.goodweathercorp.perappbrightness&hl=en_US&gl=US You probably contributed to half the code in this app

Comment: @CommonsWare How does Greenify force close apps? I'm asking for something similar, but more like restart them than close them

Comment: "as you might know I'm already doing it" -- yes. However, Google is not a fan of apps using accessibility services for non-accessibility purposes. Yours is probably on the edge of being legitimately considered "accessibility", so with luck, you won't get banned from the Play Store on the next purge of accessibility services. "How does Greenify force close apps?" -- I have no idea. But "a specific method in Android to delay or stop the launch of an app" can be interpreted as "a specific method for malware to stop the launch of the Settings app, or delay its launch by several years".

Comment: You're relying on old info. Google updated their "threats" and said that non-disability uses of accessibility are allowed so long as the reason for its use are clearly explained to the user.

Comment: So I just installed Greenify to see how it force closes apps and it seems to use an accessibility service to do it, specifically it uses "Retrieve window content" to open an app's "App info" page and then click the "Force Stop" button by itself. Any idea how they do this?

Comment: Stopping an android app isn't terminating an app. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Comment: @paladin I just need the app to get recreated.

Comment: Create an app which fakes an ultra high CPU/Memory demand and Android will kill most other running user apps. But I don't know how a user app may be able to recreate other apps, which are not familiar, at least not automatically. Maybe with a virtual pointer device, but something like this needs root rights.

Comment: Definitely with root access it should be easier. Greenify seems to be able to automatically force stop apps when there's root access without the need for an accessibility service.